# How can I check similarity in meaning and not just having same words between two texts with spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, similarity, semantics

I'm trying to compare two different texts—one coming from a Curriculum Vitae (CV) and the other from a job announcement.

After cleaning the texts, I'm trying to compare them to detect if a job announcement is more linked to a specific CV.

I am trying to do this using similarity matching in spaCy via the following code:

```py
similarity = pdf_text.similarity(final_text_from_annonce)
```

This works well, but I'm getting strange results from two different CVs for the same job announcement. Specifically, I get the same similarity score (~0.6), however, one should clearly be higher than the other.

I checked on spaCy website and I found this very important sentence:

> Vector averaging means that the vector of multiple tokens is insensitive to the order of the words. Two documents expressing the same meaning with dissimilar wording will return a lower similarity score than two documents that happen to contain the same words while expressing different meanings.

So, what do I need to use or code to make spaCy compare my two texts based on their *meaning* instead of the occurrence of words?

I am expecting a parameter for the `similarity` function of spaCy, or another function that will compare my both texts and calculate a similarity score based on the meaning of the texts and not if the same words are used.

Comment: While I sympathize with your situation, this isn't really a question about programming and is off-topic.  This may be more suitable for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chris I disagree. The OP is asking (in many words) whether a semantic similarity matching feature (an algorithm) is present in spaCy (a software tool commonly used by programmers in the field of NLP): the question is both specific, practical and answerable. The answer is that he needs to use some form of Encoder-based Transformer language model to create (proper) sentence embeddings (e.g. [USE](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder/)) instead of the average of word embeddings of words in a sentence that spaCy uses by default. This is not a data science question.

Comment: If you feel capable of providing a suitable answer to the question why not do so, instead of trying to convince us that model selection isn't a data science topic.

Comment: @Chris The question isn't about model selection, it's about a specific algorithm within a software library (semantic similarity calculation within spaCy). I've provided an answer in good faith even though it is besides the point. The [on-topic guidance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the Data Science SE site actually states that "If you have a programming or implementation question that can be answered without reference to data, it is better suited for Stack Overflow." Other points on that page suggest that this question would be actually be off-topic for that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spaCy library by default](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity) will use the average of the [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) of words in a sentence to determine semantic similarity. This can be thought of as a naive [sentence embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_embedding) approach. Such an approach could work, but if you were to use it is recommended that you first filter non-meaningful words (e.g. common words) to prevent them from undesirably influencing the final sentence embeddings.

The alternative (and more reliable) solution is to use a different pipeline within spaCy that has been designed to use sentence embeddings created specifically with a dedicated sentence encoder (e.g. the [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/collections/universal-sentence-encoder/) (USE) [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11175.pdf) by Cer et al.). Martino Mensio created a package called [spacy-universal-sentence-encoder](https://github.com/MartinoMensio/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder) that makes use of this model. Install it via the following command in your command prompt:

```
pip install spacy-universal-sentence-encoder
```

Then you can compute the semantic similarity between sentences as follows:

```py
import spacy_universal_sentence_encoder

# Load one of the models: ['en_use_md', 'en_use_lg', 'xx_use_md', 'xx_use_lg']
nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('en_use_lg')

# Create two documents
doc_1 = nlp('Hi there, how are you?')
doc_2 = nlp('Hello there, how are you doing today?')

# Use the similarity method to compare the full documents (i.e. sentences)
print(doc_1.similarity(doc_2))  # Output: 0.9356049733134972
# Or make the comparison using a predefined span of the second document 
print(doc_1.similarity(doc_2[0:7])) # Output: 0.9739387861159459
```

As a side note, when you run the `nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('en_use_lg')` command for the first time, you may have to do so with administrator rights to allow TensorFlow to create the `models` folder in `C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages\spacy_universal_sentence_encoder` and download the appropriate model. If you don't, it is possible that there will be a `PermissionDeniedError` and the code will not run.

### References

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11175.pdf) Cer, D., Yang, Y., Kong, S.Y., Hua, N., Limtiaco, N., John, R.S., Constant, N., Guajardo-Cespedes, M., Yuan, S., Tar, C. and Sung, Y.H., 2018. Universal sentence encoder. arXiv preprint arXiv:1803.11175.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This is very clear I'm sure it should word for english models. But after some researchs It seems thats french models can't be applied with this code as universal_sentence_encoder don't work yet with french models.

Comment: @AdrienVillemin I believe it does, you just have to use a multilingual model (e.g. `xx_use_md` or `xx_use_lg`. These models should be based off the Tensorflow models [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual) and [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large) respectively. If you follow those links you'll see that French is one of the 16 supported languages.