# Issue with memory when using spacy_universal_sentence_encoder for similarity detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, spacy

I'm using `spacy_universal_sentence_encoder` (https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder) for a plagiarism detection app.

I found the model to be practical and more accurate (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113939/spacy-strange-similarity-between-two-sentences/74593161), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173490/how-can-i-check-similarity-in-meaning-and-not-just-having-same-words-between-two/75193330#75193330)) for plagiarism detection after having tested out some other libraries.

When using to test with 'simple' sentences as examples as following :

```
import spacy_universal_sentence_encoder

# Load one of the models: ['en_use_md', 'en_use_lg', 'xx_use_md', 'xx_use_lg']
nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('xx_use_lg')
doc1 = nlp("Toto va à l'école avec son nouveau sac.")
doc2 = nlp("Toto came to school today with a new bag.")

# Similarity of two documents
print("Similarity of two texts : ", doc1, "<->", doc2, doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

I get the following output

```
2024-03-28 18:28:21.505655: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-28 18:28:38.693139: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Similarity of two texts :  Toto va à l'école avec son nouveau sac. <-> Toto came to school today with a new bag. 0.8622567857770158
```

The thing is in my plagiarism detection app, I'm checking a submission (which can be a whole document) against a group of documents as well. Here then, it'll be many more than just a sentence or two being checked.

```
def check_similarity(document_to_check_against: str, document_to_check: str) -> float:
    """Check similarity between two given texts using spacy."""
    nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('xx_use_lg')
    doc1 = nlp(document_to_check_against)
    doc2 = nlp(document_to_check)
    similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)
    return similarity
```

That gives me a warning : `W external/local_tsl/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 9059656832 exceeds 10% of free system memory` that makes the server crash.
I looked up and it relates to some batch size I can reduce. Where could I reduce batch size here ? I mean, is the batch size here the amount of text of documents being processed ?
How could I fix this ?